# Loading Javascript via *.js then Calling JavaScript Function

Tags: c#, javascript, browser

I have done lots of reading up but I don’t understand why this is not working. I am using VS2010 with current updates. I want to Load a Web Page into the C# Web Browser Control (This Application is a Windows Forms Application):

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://mydomain/L1/L2/L3/L4/webpage.asp");
this.webBrowser1.PerformLayout();
```

In my understanding, to call Javascript Functions from C#, one would use:

```
this.webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("passwordReset");
```

or if one had Parameters to pass:

```
object[] parameters = new object[3];
parameters[0] = “1”;
parameters[0] = false;
parameters[0] = “3”;

webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("passwordReset", parameters);
```

My Web Page code is as follows. I have shown both methods I have tried. One seems to work, if I insert the Javascript into the page.

I don’t want to work with this method due to limitations I have. I need to be able to call the *.js File as shown:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Test Page...</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javaScript"> 
function passwordReset()
{
alert("You're about to change your password!!");
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/L1/L2/Password_Reset.js"></script>

</head>
```

Please note, I am not including both Javascripts in my page at the same time. I have only included both in this example.

Can someone please explain why this method, when calling on functions in the “Password_Reset.js” file, is not working as desired?

I have tried setting full permissions: [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]

and also making this app Com Visible: [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]

EDIT: What I am trying to achieve, is to be able to run Javascripts after webBrowser1.Navigate("URL"); when they are written into the page code as Follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/L1/L2/Password_Reset.js"></script>
```

EDIT: In Re-Reading my question, I wonder if this issue is a Folder Level problem and the Script is not loading? Can someone advise on this?

Comment: To give a little more information, I can call a control on the page that has the Javascript function and it then does work:  doc.GetElementById("RSP_listDropdown").InvokeMember("onchange") and the onchange element has the same Javascript function: E.G: <select name="RSP:listDropdown" id="RSP_listDropdown" class="DDLClass" onchange="passwordReset();"> So this proves the script is loading and there. Its just i cant seem to invoke it directly. So this does not work: <script type="text/javascript" src="/L1/L2/Password_Reset.js"></script> then InvokeMember("passwordReset") method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, in the end, very simple, and a little on the obvious side. I am a little embarrased.

Once the Browser Control Document Completed:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowserTest_DocumentCompleted);
```

Event has been called, and when:

```
webBrowser1.PerformLayout();
```

has been run, the Javascripts, at this stage has not fully loaded from what I can see. If I set a delay timer up and count a 1000 milliseconds then call my Javascript, the whole thing works perfectly. This is unless, by delaying the calls to my javascript, are in-turn allowing another issue in the background to resolve itself?

I guess the next thing to solve, is why is the DocumentCompleted eventhandler not including the loading of scripts in the way one would expect.

I hope others find this usefull and it saves them the time I spend resolving ths issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to accomplish.

However, I suggest you to look at startup script registration methods. If you use them, a JavaScript function will be executed in client browser after html document loading.

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) article. Maybe you can use it solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my app is not server side, its client side. It only calls asp pages or any pages for that matter, html, asp or what ever.